# Non stick pan browning milk vs stainless steel

Tags: temperature, milk, non-stick, stainless-steel, induction

We recently purchased a nonstick medium pot but have been encountering problems while making mac & cheese. The milk seems to be browning/toasting with all settings on our induction cooker remaining the same. Previously we utilized a stainless steel pan and encountered no problems.

What is the cause for whole milk browning and needing to be skimmed?

Answer (score 2):

With all other settings being the same, following can possibly cause the milk stick to the bottom:

1. **Pan is not suitable for induction hob** 
   According to [Good Housekeeping Institute](https://www.goodhousekeeping.co.uk/institute/product-reviews/buying-guides/how-to-buy-the-best-pots-and-pans), the only suitable pans are ones 
   made with a magnetic material in the base, such as cast iron or stainless 
   steel. Pure aluminium or copper pans will not work on an induction hob unless 
   the base is bonded with a magnetic metal.
2. **Non-stick coating is too thin** 
   Non-stick coatings are applied to various types of cookware, from aluminium and 
   steel to cast iron and stainless steel. If the coating is too thin, it can 
   cause heat distribution problems causing food to stick and burn.
3. **Bottom of the pan is thin** 
   Thin bottomed pans are also prone to food burning and sticking to the bottom. As you're providing the same amount of heat, it will transfer to the food quickly and cause it to burn at the bottom. As a general rule, heavy-bottom pans are best.